# Trouble with Javascript Date

Tags: javascript

I know my attempt it terrible, but this is what I got. I'm trying to get the current date to display in this fashion: Monday, 19 February 2018. Can anyone fix this mess into a working Javascript code?

```
var dayname = new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday");

var monthname = new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November", "December");

var d=new Date();
var today = dayname[d.getDay()] + ", " + d.getDate() + " " + monthname[d.getMonth()] + " " + d.getFullYear();
document.getElementById('currentdate").innerHTML = today;
```

Comment: Using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) would make this much easier.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: syntax error, replace this ('currentdate") with ("currentdate").

Comment: careful... getMonths() starts at zero, getDays() starts at 1....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax error here `'currentdate"` either use all `""` or `''` otherwise your code is working just fine...

```js
var dayname = new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday");

var monthname = new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November", "December");

var d=new Date();
var today = dayname[d.getDay()] + ", " + d.getDate() + " " + monthname[d.getMonth()] + " " + d.getFullYear();
document.getElementById('currentdate').innerHTML = today;
// Put a ' instead of "                 ^ here
```

```html
<div id="currentdate"></div>
```

The approach I would suggest you here is to still use [`moment.js`](https://momentjs.com/)

```js
var date = moment().format("dddd, Do MMMM YYYY");
console.log(date);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @brk yea I was editing my answer to give him the **moment.js** approach.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var dayname = new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday");

var monthname = new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November", "December");

var d=new Date();
var today = dayname[d.getDay()] + ", " + d.getDate() + " " + monthname[d.getMonth()] + " " + d.getFullYear();
document.getElementById("currentdate").innerHTML = today;
```

```html
<span id="currentdate"></span>
```

`document.getElementById('currentdate")` this is the problem. you have used one `'` and `"`